# Using Windows.Networking.Sockets in Unity3D

Tags: c#, sockets, unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I am trying to port our Unity application for Windows Store and so far I cannot get the SDK to work. I've gotten up to the point where I can open Unity C# project in Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop (which is odd because "... for Windows" cannot open Unity project, yet is needed for the development). The macros `#if UNITY_WINRT` started to work, but I cannot seem to get the "using" part right

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
#if UNITY_WINRT
using Windows.Networking.Sockets;
#else
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
#endif
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

and the `Windows.Networking.Sockets` is underlined as wrong, generally, the `using Windows` doesn't seem to be present ... what am I doing wrong? Should I add something to the using part? Should I add some library?

Now I get why Windows Phone has so few app developers if the development setup is so hard and restricted compared to Android or iOS (well this is restricted, but setup is easy).

Thank you very much for your help ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I got it up and running. I created a DLL library in C# (managed) in Visual Studio. Then I called the methods I needed from within mu Unity application.

Comment: My first reaction to your question was that you needed to use WINDOWS_PHONE || NETFX_CORE  instead of UNITY_WINRT but I can't seem to get Visual Studio to run the WINDOWS_PHONE or NETFX_CORE code.   So now I am looking at creating a DLL as well. How did you go about it?   I am not sure how to include those classes in a DLL so I created a TcpClient class in a custom DLL but Unity doesn't seem to find it when I drop it into the project. Was trying a portable class library but just did a foo bar library in .NET 3.5 and can't get that one either. Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Since your app opens in Visual Studio Express for Desktop and not in Visual Studio Express for Windows it sounds like you generated a Windows desktop project out of Unity rather than a Windows Phone project. You'll need to go back to Unity and regenerate the Visual Studio solution as a Windows Store or Windows Phone solution. Also make sure your VS Express has at least Update 2 to allow Windows Phone projects. Even better: upgrade to [Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-community-vs.aspx) instead of using VS Express. It's still free, but is equivalent to VS Pro and (most importantly) will run [Visual Studio Tools for Unity](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/20b80b8c-659b-45ef-96c1-437828fe7cf2).

You'll need to use #if NETFX_CORE instead of (or in addition to) UNITY_WINRT to use the Windows Runtime. UNITY_WINRT will allow for targeting specific functionality to Windows Phone or Windows Store, but it will still run in the Unity editor (which is mono, not Windows Runtime). NETFX_CORE will be true only when running on the Windows Runtime and not on mono.

Comment: I have chosen `Windows Store` as the target. But the project cannot be opened in VS for Windows - it says that it cannot open projects other than Windows Store. I will try the community version, but I am not sure if I can use it - since it is a commercial project for my startup company. Gotta talk with my lawyer about that. My aim is for the Windows tablets and built-in devices (which are supposed to be Windows RT). I tried and the target `Windows Desktop` compiles and runs well - but it does not use the touch SDK (which I need)

Comment: Oh and BTW: I'd rather use the MonoDevelop (because I'm used to it from Mac OS X Unity), but I thought that the VS has better luck of running the Windows magic

Comment: If your solution opens in VS Express for Desktop then it isn't a Windows Store app solution. Double check you're building it out the way you think you are. You probably want the Universal 8.1 sub-type. If it won't open in either VS Express for Desktop or for Windows then make sure your VS is fully updated. VS Community won't help target Windows RT if the solution isn't a Windows Runtime solution. VS Community can be used by small teams for commercial purposes - point your lawyer at https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs for the licence terms and licensing whitepaper